# "runter" im Sinne von "hinunter"

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Kann *runter* im Sinne von *hinunter* (d.h. ausdehnend) verwendet werden, bspw. im Zusammenhang mit dem Verb "fahren"?
Ich habe eine Vermutung, dass das sowohl im süddeutschen, aber auch ost- und norddeutschen Raum möglich ist.

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage möchtest du das als eine Antwort schreiben? Oder sollte ich lieber die Frage löschen?

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, vielleicht kann jemand eine schöne Antwort mit Beispielen aus dem alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch schreiben.

Comment: Auf dieselbe Weise wird auch noch "rein" "missbraucht". Vielen Deutschen scheint es schwierig zu sein, zwischen Zusammensetzungen von hin- und her-  mit Präpositionen zu unterscheiden.
Interessant wäre, wo man dieser Tendenz zuwider eigentlich "nein" sagt im Sinne von "hinein". Aber ich weiß nicht nicht, wie man das am besten in eine Frage verpackt. Allerdings kam ich auch deswegen auf den Gedanken, die Frage zu löschen und neu erstellen.

Comment: Meinst du z. B. statt "Leg das da hinein" "Leg das da nein"? Das habe ich so noch nicht gehört, eher mit "nei" ("Leg das da nei").

Comment: Genau, aber in diesem Fall kann man das "nei" grob gesagt als "nein" einstufen. Es gibt nämlich Dialekte, wo man "neinschmieten" sagt für "reinschmeißen". Wäre interessant, inwieweit das für das regionale Varietäten (as opposed to dialects) characteristisch ist.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, das kann man insbesondere im süddeutschen Raum so verwenden.

- Einen Berg runterfahren.
- Den Rechner runterfahren.

Dabei sind sowohl runter als auch rauf, finde ich, sehr spannende Wörter. Runter von herunter sowie hinunter. Beides sind sehr perspektivische Wörter, wobei her-unter, wie das Wort schon sagt, einen Abstieg von einem relativ zum aktuellen Standpunkt erhöhten Punkt auf dieselbe Ebene beschreibt, also ein Herkommen. 
Auf der andere Seite dann hin-unter, das einen Abstieg vom aktuellen Punkt auf einen niedrigeren Punkt beschreibt, ein Hingehen also. Dasselbe funktioniert natürlich auch für den Aufstieg: rauf, respektive hinauf, herauf. Auch hier wieder ein Hin-/Hergehen auf den respektive höheren Punkt.

Comment: Ja, interessant ist auch, dass es doch kein "rab" gibt, sondern nur "rauf", Anstelle "rab" haben wir dann das "runter".

Comment: Im schwäbischen gibt es allerdings sowohl "nab" als auch "nauf" als Abkürzung für "hinab" bzw. "hinauf"...

Comment: @TorstenLink aber doch kein "rab", oder?

Comment: Im Norden/Osten Deutschlands wird generell die verkürzte Form mit 'r- verwendet, unabhängig davon, ob die lange Version bei korrekter Differenzierung ein hin- oder ein her- erfordert (also *hinunter* und *herunter* werden umgangssprachlich beide zu *runter*. Die Verkürzung mit 'n- ('nunter) ist typisch süddeutsch/österreichisch.

Comment: @Dan Doch, mir ist sowohl ra/na für die absteigenden bzw. rauf/nauf für die aufsteigenden Bewegungen im Schwäbischen bekannt. Ebenso wir im Schwäbischen auch zwischen raus/naus und rei/nei Unterschieden welche die Bewegung aus bzw. in einen Ort beschreiben. Die genaue Aussprache mag sich hier von Region zu Region unterscheiden. Und danke Volker.

Answer (score 4):

Beim Blick in den Zweifelsfallsduden (Duden 9, 8. Auflage) zum Stichwort *runter* wird man nur an das Stichwort *Apostroph* verwiesen. Immerhin wird dort (SS. 85–86) zwischen *n-* anlautenden Kürzungen (*'nan*, *'nauf*, *'naus*, *'nein*, *'nüber*, *'nunter*) und *r-* anlautenden Kürzungen (*ran*, *rauf*, *raus*, *rein*, *rüber*, *runter*) unterschieden. (Letztere würden üblicherweise ohne Apostroph verwendet, weil man sie als selbstständige Nebenformen ansehe.)

Demnach könnte man zunächst vermuten, *n-* anlautende Kürzungen würden nur Adverbien mit *hin-* und *r-* anlautenden Kürzungen nur Adverbien mit *her-* ersetzen.

Zumindest in Ostdeutschland, wo ich aufgewachsen bin, ist das definitiv nicht so! Hier werden ausnahmslos die *r-* anlautenden Kürzungen verwendet, und zwar gleichermaßen für Adverbien mit *her-* und *hin-*. Einen Sprecher oder Schreiber, der oft *n-* anlautende Kürzungen wie im nachfolgenden Beispiel verwendet, würde ich sofort dem süddeutschen Raum zuordnen:

> „Gehen S' die Treppen 'nauf!“

**Beispiele für den Gebrauch in Ostdeutschland:**

> runter
>
> - Kommst du bald runter (*her*unter)?
> - Sie lief schnell die Treppe runter (*hin*unter)!
>
> raus
>
> - Er kam zu uns raus. (*her*aus)
> - Bei dem Wetter gehe ich gern raus (*hin*aus).
>
> rein
>
> - Komm ruhig rein (*her*ein)!
> - Beim Reinfahren (*Hin*einfahren) gleich links!
>
> ...

Übrigens schrieb vor einhundert Jahren schon Eduard Engel in seinem großartigen Werk *Deutsche Stilkunst* (2. Auflage des Nachdrucks aus dem Persephone Verlag, Zürich, 2017):

> „Daß Hin und Her etwas Verschiedenes bedeuten, ahnt zwar der Nord- und Mitteldeutsche, hält das aber nur für eine bedeutungslose Lehrmeinung; der Süddeutsche fühlt es und spricht demgemäß so lange richtig, wie er nicht durch die allgemeindeutsche Schriftsprache, besonders durch die norddeutschen Zeitungen stumpfgeworden.“ (S. 82)

Und weiter:

> „Eine Ausnahme von der sonst strengen Regel bilden einige derbe Zeitwörter wie rauswerfen, rausschmeißen, reinfallen, die übrigens in Süddeutschland meist mit n ('nauswerfen) gebraucht werden. Vielleicht hat das rollende R mit seiner stärkeren Tonmalerei dazu verführt.“ (S. 83)