# Lokaladverbien: raus, rein, rauf, runter, rüber

Tags: adverb

Ich habe [auf dieser Website](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/lokaladverbien.html) (am Ende der Seite) gelesen, dass "raus, rein, rauf, runter, rüber" Abkürzungen der beiden Lokaladverbien "hinaus und heraus" (raus), "hinein und herein" (rein), "hinauf und herauf" (rauf), "hinunter und herunter" (runter) und "hinüber und herüber" (rüber) ... sind. Ich frage mich, ob das richtig ist, weil ich das Gefühl habe, dass weil die Abkürzungen mit R beginnen, sie sich nur auf die Vorsilbe her- (R am Ende) beziehen.

Wenn, z. B. "raus" beides, "hinaus" und "heraus" bedeuten kann, wie kann man sie voneinander unterscheiden?

Comment: Warum muss man sie denn unterscheiden? Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen heraus und hinaus?

Comment: @infinitezero der Unterschied besteht darin, ob die Bewegung auf den Beobachter/Sprecher zu oder von ihm weg erfolgt.

Comment: Umgangssprachlich würde ich behaupten, wird beides synonym verwendet, zumindest war mir der Unterschied bislang aktiv nicht bewusst. Selbiges dürfte dann wahrscheinlich auch für raus gelten.

Comment: @infinitezero Ich habe weiter im Internet über diese Thema gesucht und ich habe den Unterschied zwischen heraus und hinaus zufällig (laut einem Lehrer) gefunden: "Der Polizist kommt HERAUS" (wer das sagt IST NICHT WO so etwas passiert ist) und "Der Polizist kommt HEREIN" (wer das sagt IST WO so etwas passiert ist). Aber ich nehme an, dass man vielleicht diese Unterschied in der Umgangssprache nicht macht...

Comment: Dieses Thema hatten wir übrigens gerade vor ein paar Wochen gehabt, bin aber momentan zu beschäftigt um selber zu suchen

Comment: Hier ein kleiner Test: *"Das läuft auf dasselbe hinaus" vs. "Das läuft auf dasselbe heraus"*. - Welcher Satz kommt Ihnen komisch vor? - Es läuft darauf **hinaus**, dass zwischen hinaus und heraus eben doch ein Unterschied besteht und dass die Wörter nicht vertauschbar sind. Das kommt jedenfalls **heraus**, wenn man gründlich drüber nachdenkt. Darüber**hinaus** würde man die Antwort dazu wohl auch in einem guten Wörterbuch finden. **Heraus** mit der Sprache, habe ich recht?

Comment: zuminest landschaftlich gibt es aber wohl auch *naus*, *nunter*, ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["runter" im Sinne von "hinunter"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53466/runter-im-sinne-von-hinunter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beim Blick in den Zweifelsfallsduden (Duden 9, 8. Auflage) zum Stichwort *runter* wird man nur an das Stichwort *Apostroph* verwiesen. Immerhin wird dort (SS. 85–86) zwischen *n-* anlautenden Kürzungen (*'nan*, *'nauf*, *'naus*, *'nein*, *'nüber*, *'nunter*) und *r-* anlautenden Kürzungen (*ran*, *rauf*, *raus*, *rein*, *rüber*, *runter*) unterschieden. (Letztere würden üblicherweise ohne Apostroph verwendet, weil man sie als selbstständige Nebenformen ansehe.)

Demnach könnte man zunächst vermuten, *n-* anlautende Kürzungen würden nur Adverbien mit *hin-* und *r-* anlautenden Kürzungen nur Adverbien mit *her-* ersetzen.

Zumindest in Ostdeutschland, wo ich aufgewachsen bin, ist das definitiv nicht so! Hier werden ausnahmslos die *r-* anlautenden Kürzungen verwendet, und zwar gleichermaßen für Adverbien mit *her-* und *hin-*. Einen Sprecher oder Schreiber, der oft *n-* anlautende Kürzungen wie im nachfolgenden Beispiel verwendet, würde ich sofort dem süddeutschen Raum zuordnen:

> „Gehen S' die Treppen 'nauf!“

**Beispiele für den Gebrauch in Ostdeutschland:**

> runter
>
> - Kommst du bald runter (*her*unter)?
> - Sie lief schnell die Treppe runter (*hin*unter)!
>
> raus
>
> - Er kam zu uns raus. (*her*aus)
> - Bei dem Wetter gehe ich gern raus (*hin*aus).
>
> rein
>
> - Komm ruhig rein (*her*ein)!
> - Beim Reinfahren (*Hin*einfahren) gleich links!
>
> ...

Übrigens schrieb vor einhundert Jahren schon Eduard Engel in seinem großartigen Werk *Deutsche Stilkunst* (2. Auflage des Nachdrucks aus dem Persephone Verlag, Zürich, 2017):

> „Daß Hin und Her etwas Verschiedenes bedeuten, ahnt zwar der Nord- und Mitteldeutsche, hält das aber nur für eine bedeutungslose Lehrmeinung; der Süddeutsche fühlt es und spricht demgemäß so lange richtig, wie er nicht durch die allgemeindeutsche Schriftsprache, besonders durch die norddeutschen Zeitungen stumpfgeworden.“ (S. 82)

Und weiter:

> „Eine Ausnahme von der sonst strengen Regel bilden einige derbe Zeitwörter wie rauswerfen, rausschmeißen, reinfallen, die übrigens in Süddeutschland meist mit n ('nauswerfen) gebraucht werden. Vielleicht hat das rollende R mit seiner stärkeren Tonmalerei dazu verführt.“ (S. 83)

Comment: "würde ich sofort dem süddeutschen Raum zuordnen" - ich habe persönlich ein Mädchen aus MePo erlebt, das so gesprochen hat.

Answer (score 2):

Die Abkürzungen

> raus, rein, rauf, runter, rüber

bedeuten dasselbe wie

> heraus, herein, herauf, herunter, herüber

Manchmal findet man diese Abkürzungen auch in geschriebenen Texten.

---

Manche Dialekte kennen auch

> 'naus, 'nein, 'nauf, 'nunter, 'nüber

als Abkürzung für

> hinaus, hinein, hinauf, hinunter, hinüber

Diese Abkürzungen werden von den meisten Deutschsprechern verstanden, allerdings nur von den Sprechern dieser Dialekte benutzt. In geschriebenen Texten sind diese Abkürzungen extrem selten, da sie einen Dialektsprecher markieren.

---

In den Dialekten, die *'naus, 'nein* etc. **nicht** kennen, wird stattdessen *raus, rein*, etc. verwendet.

> Geh mal bitte raus. → Geh mal bitte **hinaus**.

Hier geht also der Unterschied zwischen *hinaus* und *heraus* verloren. Das gilt allerdings nur für die Kurzform. Bittet man den Sprecher eines solchen Dialektes, zu erklären, was gemeint ist, wird er bei diesem Beispiel **hinaus** antworten, nicht *heraus*.

Comment: "In den Dialekten, die 'naus, 'nein etc. nicht kennen". Es geht vielmehr um ein gemeindeutsches Phänomen. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rein_hinein_herein

Comment: *raus, rein* etc sind auch Dialektausdrücke, die allerdings im Gegensatz zu 'naus, 'nein ihren Weg in den Duden gefunden haben. Ich sehe daher keinen Grund, sie anders zu behandeln.

Comment: Ich weise nur darauf hin, dass der Duden es eher als ein gemeindeutsches Merkmal der Umgangssprache bezeichnet, das aus ihrer Sicht nicht mehr als dialektal oder landschaftlich zu bezeichnen ist.